# Visual SVN Server post-commit-hook parameters are not commited

Tags: visualsvn-server

With Visual SVN Server on Tab hooks list post-commit

I added a filename with full path in this window, but if I do a commit, parameters are not sent to my executable. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found it myself:

It's not enough to insert the path to executeable in this multiline box. This box edits the batch-file directly, which will be executed, so the params %1 , %2 must be added here.

Adding %* helped. In case spaces are used in path, this is fine for me:

```
"c:\...mypath...\myFile.bat" "%1" %2
```